# Console.log displays elements from array of objects correctly but innerHTML does not

Tags: javascript, html

**Console.log(data[i].title) displays the correct output but when I try to display it using innerHTML only one result is returned.**

I am new to coding and I am working on a web-scrapper project. I have a server running that grabs the headlines of NBC news and inputs the data into an array. When I try to display the data on my frontend using console.log it returns the right results but when I try to display the results on my html page it just returns the final result. The results are shown in the attached image.

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYg8y.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="list"></div>
        <input type="text" id="input"></input><br>
        <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button><br><br>
        <p id="p"></p>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

```js
const PORT= 8000;
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const express = require('express')
const cors= require('cors');
const { html } = require('cheerio/lib/static');
// to run this use 'npm run start' in the terminal 

const url = 'https://www.nbcnews.com/';
const app = express();
app.use(cors())
app.get('/results', (req, res) => {
    axios(url)
    //var x = req.body.input
    .then(response=> {
        const article= []
        const html=response.data;
        const $=cheerio.load(html);
        $('.alacarte__headline', html).each(function(){
            const title= $(this).text()
            //._13svhQIUZqD9PVzFcLwOKT styled-outbound-link
            article.push({
                title
            })
        
           
        })
        res.json(article)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))

})


app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`))
```

```js
const feedDisplay= document.querySelector('#list');
fetch('http://localhost:8000/results')
    .then(response => {
        return response.json()
    
    })
    .then(data=> {
        var x= ''
        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            
            console.log(data[i].title)
            document.getElementById("p").innerHTML=(data[i].title)
            
           
        }
```

Comment: Your innerHTML loop overwrites the content set in each prior iteration of the loop so all you see is the last one. Try using `+=` instead of `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:
`document.getElementById("p").innerHTML=(data[i].title)` you are setting new value of `innerHTML`. This replaces previous value.

You can use [array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to get list of all titles and then join them using [array join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method.

I used `' '` space as separator, but you can replace it with any string.

```js
const feedDisplay= document.querySelector('#list');
fetch('http://localhost:8000/results')
    .then(response => {
        return response.json()
    
    })
    .then(data => {
        document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = data.map(d => d.title).join(' ')
    }
```